# Entry values are changed in configuration.php

Tags: joomla-4, configuration

In the configuration.php of Joomla 4.2, entries are changed when saving.

Entries with = '1'; are changed to = true; and entries with = '0'; or = ''; are changed to = false;.

I think this has to do with types. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct. The [`Joomla\Registry\Format\Php`](https://api.joomla.org/framework-2/classes/Joomla-Registry-Format-Php.html) class responsible for writing the configuration file now supports outputting correct data types. Previously values were essentially cast to string so, for example, boolean `false` resulted in an empty string. What data types are used for writing `configuration.php` depends on the form field filters defined in the form definition.